# Swagger Editor integration to Git or GitHub

Tags: git, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I'm currently using the [Swagger Editor](http://editor.swagger.io) locally in my network. Is there any possibility that the editor can import a file directly from a git server?

I'm defining an API and I would like to have that in git, not only to have it secure but to collaborate with other programmers.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I am looking for a similar use case. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No I didn't, @AndyDufresne. I ended up using SwaggerHub or Apiary.io

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a link to the 'raw' file from Github.

```
https://editor.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/branch/swagger.yml
```

Comment: @bluelurker this is still working for me.  Can you post your swagger file url?

Answer (score 1):

Two options that we use in our office:

(1) Microsoft Code has great Swagger editor plugins. I personally use the `Swagger Viewer` v3.0.1 plugin.

(2) The Stoplight.io tool-set includes a local swagger editor for Mac/PC and supports complete Git integration.